# Only allowing certain characters in a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to disallow all symbols in a string, and instead of going and disallowing each one I thought it'd be easier to just allow alphanumeric characters (a-z A-Z 0-9).

How would I go about parsing a string and converting it to one which only has allowed characters? I also want to convert any spaces into `_`.

At the moment I have:

```
function parseFilename($name) {
    $allowed = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
    $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);

    return $name;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP regex, replace all trash symbols with underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089503/php-regex-replace-all-trash-symbols-with-underscores)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to strip out everything but words and numbers (and latin chars)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982915/regex-to-strip-out-everything-but-words-and-numbers-and-latin-chars)

Comment: or [PHP: the best way to remove punctuation marks, symbols, diacritics, special characters, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762546/php-the-best-way-to-remove-punctuation-marks-symbols-diacritics-special-char)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do both replacements at once by using arrays as the `find` / `replace` params in `preg_match()`:

```
$str = 'abc def+ghi&jkl   ...z';
$find = array( '#[\s]+#','#[^\w]+#' );
$replace = array( '_','' );
$newstr = preg_replace( $find,$replace,$str );
print $newstr;

// outputs:
// abc_defghijkl_z
```

`\s` matches whitespace (replaced with a single underscore), and as @F.J described, `^\w` is anything "not a word character" (replaced with empty string).

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace()` is the way to go here, the following should do what you want:

```
function parseFilename($name) {
    $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
    $name = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '', $name);
    return $name;
}
```

`[^\w]` is equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which will match any character that is not alphanumeric or an underscore.  The `+` after it means match one or more, this should be slightly more efficient than replacing each character individually.

Answer (score 0):

The replacement if spaces with spaces does not require the might of the regex engine; it can wait out the first round of replacements.

The purging of all non-alphanumeric characters and underscores is concisely handled by `\W` -- it means any character not in `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, or `_`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/d4duv))

```
function sanitizeFilename(string $name): string {
    return preg_replace(
               '/\W+/',
               '',
               str_replace(' ', '_', $name)
           );
}

echo sanitizeFilename('This/is My     1! FilenAm3');
```

Output:

```
Thisis_My_____1_FilenAm3
```

---

...but if you want to condense consecutive spaces and replace them with a single underscore, then use regex.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AeSnP))

```
function sanitizeFilename(string $name): string {
    return preg_replace(
               ['/ +/', '/\W+/'],
               ['_', ''],
               $name
           );
}

echo sanitizeFilename('This/has a      Gap !n 1t');
```

Output:

```
Thishas_a_Gap_n_1t
```

Answer (score -1):

Try working with the HTML part

```
pattern="[A-Za-z]{8}" title="Eight letter country code">
```

Comment: Try looking into this